# How to remove a specific point from matplotlib surfaceplot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, surface

I am trying to make a surface plot of a point cloud which is saved in text file in x,y,z format.
when i try to a surface plot, there is a point near the origin which is ruining the plot as the surface gets altered.

I tried to find the lowest value from the array of x,y,z ,turns out they are not the reason.
How can i get a clean surface plot.
Here is the code-

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
import numpy as np
def distance(x, y, z):
    return math.sqrt(x**2 + y**2 + z**2)
lim = 0.5
fig1 = plt.figure(1)
ar = Axes3D(fig1)#fig1.gca()#
ar.set_xlim(-lim,lim)
ar.set_ylim(-lim,lim)
ar.set_zlim(-lim,lim)

pointz= np.loadtxt(fname = "goddo_table_1.txt",delimiter=",", dtype=str)
x = np.empty([len(pointz),1],dtype=float)
y = np.empty([len(pointz),1],dtype=float)
z =np.empty([len(pointz),1],dtype=float)
for i in range(len(pointz) ):
    if distance(float(pointz[i][0]), float(pointz[i][1]), float(pointz[i][2])) > 0.1 and float(pointz[i][2])>0.1:
        x = np.append(x,float(pointz[i][0]))
        y = np.append(y,float(pointz[i][1]))
        z = np.append(z,float(pointz[i][2]))

    else:
        #print(float(pointz[i][0]), float(pointz[i][1]), float(pointz[i][2]))
        pass
xj = np.asarray(x)
yj = np.asarray(z)
zj = np.asarray(y)
print(np.amin(abs(xj)))
print(np.amin(abs(yj)))
print(np.amin(abs(zj)))
print("     ")
print(np.argmin(abs(xj)))
print(np.argmin(abs(yj)))
print(np.argmin(abs(zj)))

xi = np.linspace(min(xj), max(xj))
yi = np.linspace(min(yj), max(yj))
X, Y = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)


Z = griddata((xj, yj), zj, (X, Y), method='nearest')
#ar.contour(X, Y, Z)
ar.plot_surface(X, Y, Z,cmap='jet', edgecolor='none')

#surf = ar.plot_trisurf(x, z, y,cmap='viridis', edgecolor='none')
surf = ar.scatter(xj, yj, zj,s=1,c='r')
#ar.scatter(x,y,z,s=1)
ar.set_xlabel('Horizontal - axis')
ar.set_ylabel('Depth - axis')
ar.set_zlabel('Vertical   - axis')

plt.show()
```

here is the text file -[goddo_table_1.txt](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1m60dqY-5k4EPiWaMBgNTtIJFFaXtAHKh)

Here is an image of the plot -[Surface_plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dG2ta.png)

How can remove the point near the origin?What am i missing?
BTW - the point cloud made using an intel d435 camera and meshlab was used to make txt file from .ply file

Answer (score 1):

That's because you use `np.empty`, with this command you interfere wrong extra points to your surface.
just use
`X=[  ]`  `Y=[  ]` `Z=[  ]`

and then append your points to them.